# Logging Into My Website

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem with my website where a new user is able to log into his or her account but his or her details are unable to be retrieved from the database for the first time.The code below is working properly but the big problem is,if a new user logs into his or her account for the first time, The user's details are unable to be retrieved from the database.The user has to log out and log in again so that his or her details are able to be retrieved from the database.In addition,on removal of the set in the getUserField() function,It gives out this error,unable to jump to row 0,mysql_result() on logging in

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
        require'php/connection.php';
    $current_file=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
```

The below loggedin() function is used to set the current user session

```
 function loggedin()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){
            $UserId=$_SESSION['user_id'];
            return $UserId;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The below function is used to retrieve the current user details from the database

```
function getUserField($field){

        if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){
            $user_id=$_SESSION['user_id'];
        $query="select $field from `user_account` where `account_id`='$user_id'";

        if($query_run=mysql_query($query)){
            return mysql_result($query_run,0,$field);
        }
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Where is the calling part of this functions?

Comment: may you are not setting the session id after register sothat `getUserField()` will fail

Comment: Please can you give me more details on how to go about it

Comment: give me a short sample on how to set the session id after register

Answer (score 0):

You should try this in loggedin function.

change `$userId = $_SESSION['user_id']`

to

`$_SESSION['user_id'] = $userId`

I hope this will help you

Comment: have you start session in your connection.php file?

Comment: In my connection.php file,i just call the database